# Boundary conditions for my Site - SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

Any one knows the boundary conditions for the below scenarios in SharePoint 2013.

Maximum number of followed people ?

Maximum number of followed documents box?

Maximum number of followed sites box ?

Since these all configured, whats the exact recommended values?....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer for this question. Currently in preview version we configure these values and while try to set max values , it shows the validation messages.

Maximum number of followed people  - 1000

Maximum number of followed documents box - 500

Maximum number of followed sites box - 500

Answer (score 0):

You can follow people, documents, sites and configure the limits for the number of people, documents, and sites that users can follow from their My Site. But there are no recommended values as per Microsoft documentation [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.15%29.aspx):